# Add number identifier for new users in Supabase

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, supabase

I want to add a trigger in a Supabase database that adds a unique identifier for new users (upon sign-up) that is shorter than the UUID that is generated, one that can be used in routing. My plan is to simply do something similar to Facebook, where I just do something like `joe.smith` + # of "Joe Smiths" already in the database (ex. `joe.smith.12`).

To do this, I am creating a function trigger:

```
declare
  total integer; 
  first_name text;
  last_name text;
  identifier text;
  

begin
  first_name := split_part(new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', ' ', 0);
  last_name := split_part(new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', ' ', 1);
  identifier := concat(first_name, '.', last_name, '.');
  total := (select count(full_name_identifier)::int from public.profiles where full_name like concat(identifier, '%'));
  insert into public.profiles (id, full_name, avatar_url, full_name_identifier)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url', concat(identifier, cast(identifier as text)));
  return new;
end;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you get any errors or are you looking for problems with this implementation?

Comment: Assuming your trigger is defined on the table `profiles` your trigger function will duplicate each insert (because it runs _another_ insert). Typically this would be done in a `BEFORE` trigger and the values would be _assigned_ to the `new` record.